# Save and rename attachments with specific file type, without overwriting

Tags: vba, outlook, attachment

I need to send .docx files only to the specified folder.

If the file name exists then it may not be overwritten.

See below what I have found as template.

```vb
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
        saveFolder = "C:\Path\"
    Dim dateFormat As String
        dateFormat = Format(itm.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd Hmm ")
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        If FileType = ".docx" Then
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Start in here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/vba-language-reference

Comment: At a quick guess `if right(ucase(objAtt.Name),5) = ".DOCX" then`, did you just make `FileType` up?

Comment: Hi Gary, 

Yes, I tried to use FileType but that didn´t work. Nothing happened at that point. I have tried to change it into your advise, but I receive a fault on that line!!!

Comment: Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
        saveFolder = "C:\Path\"
    Dim dateFormat As String
        dateFormat = Format(itm.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd Hmm ")
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        If Right(UCase(objAtt.Name), 5) = ".docx" Then
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Here are some tips about [posting questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and about [sharing code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow).

Comment: @VBAQuestions try to put the code in markdown way and format the new line to ease the visualization.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your `IF` Statement with:

```
If Right(objAtt.Filename, 5) = ".docx" Then
```

`FileType` is for attachments to Access tables, but even if you could use it, you would need to qualify the reference (ie., tell VBA which object you want the FileType for), like:

```
If objAtt.FileType = "docx" Then
```

More about VBA with Outlook attachments [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.attachment_members.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.attachment.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).

---

### Update:

Adding a number if file already exists.  Also removed extra "\" which could cause unexpected results with the save location.

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String, dateFormat As String, fName As String
    saveFolder = "C:\Path\"
    dateFormat = Format(itm.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd Hmm ")
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        If objAtt.FileType = "docx" Then
            fName = saveFolder & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName
            If Dir(fName) <> "" Then 'file already exists
                fName = fName & Int(Timer) 'add a number
            End If
            objAtt.SaveAsFile fName & ".docx"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

### Edit #2:

Paste the code below into a module in Outlook, Excel, or Access, and specify the folder and name "prefix" for the "processed" numbered files, in the Constants  (Create the destination folder manually if it doesn't exist.) Then, function `getNextFileName` will return the "next available name" starting with `myFile0001.docx`...  Use that function to set your `objAtt.SaveAsFile` filename, or else save the file as whatever, and immediately use sub `renameSequentially(`_in_Filepath&name_`)` to rename (and possibly relocate) it.

```
Option Explicit

Function getNextFileName() As String
'returns a string with the next available filename matching the criteria in the Constants below.
    Const folder = "C:\savepathhere\"
    Const filenameStart = "myFile"
    Const filenameEnd = ".docx" 'this will become "C:\savepathhere\myFile0001.docx" etc

    Dim r As String, fileNum As Long, maxFileNum As Long
    Dim numStartPos As Integer, numStopPos As Integer, NextFileName As String

    'start listing existing files
    r = Dir(folder & filenameStart & "*" & filenameEnd)

    If r = "" Then
        maxFileNum = 0 'this will be the file #1
    Else

        Do While r <> ""

            'existing file found. Get the number from it's name
            numStartPos = Len(filenameStart) + 1
            numStopPos = InStr(numStartPos, r, filenameEnd, vbTextCompare)
            fileNum = Val(Mid(r, numStartPos, numStopPos - numStartPos))
            If fileNum > maxFileNum Then maxFileNum = fileNum

            'get next filename
            r = Dir
        Loop

    End If

    'get the new filename
    NextFileName = folder & "\" & filenameStart & Format(maxFileNum + 1, "0000") & filenameEnd
    Debug.Print "Next unusued filename: " & NextFileName

    'double-check that it's available
    If Dir(NextFileName) <> "" Then
        MsgBox "Error! Filename taken: " & NextFileName
        Exit Function
    End If

    getNextFileName = NextFileName

End Function

Function renameSequentially(in_File As String)
'specify path+filename that should be renamed requentiallyto should be renamed sequentially
    Dim newName As String
    newName = getNextFileName
    Name in_File As newName
    If Dir(newName) <> "" Then
        MsgBox in_File & vbLf & " was renamed to:" & vbLf & newName
    Else
        Call MsgBox("Something went wrong trying to rename" & vbLf & in_File & vbLf & " to " & vbLf & newName, vbExclamation, vbOKOnly)
    End If
End Function

Sub test()
renameSequentially ("C:\mysourcepath\abcwxyz.docx") 'renames the file to myfile####.docx
End Sub
```

Comment: Dear Ashleedawg, Thank you very much for your answer. The part of ´only´ .docx is solved. Do you know how to add a number if the filename already exists?

Comment: It looks like you're already adding a date & time to the filename. Will there sometimes be more than one attachment per minute? Anyway, see my edited answer above.  (Your additional code should also be added to your Question instead of a comment.)

Comment: Dear Ashleedawg, Unfortunatelly yes. And it goes so far that someone send every time 2 documents with the same name but with another content. (These 2 documents are on a different location on his drive, and the situation is now that I can process just 1 document with this automated process).

Comment: Dear Ashleedawg, I have tested your latest update and it will not add an extra number to the filename if it already exists.

The results are the same as before.

Comment: This is my latest script

Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem) Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment Dim saveFolder As String, dateFormat As String, fName As String saveFolder = "C:\Path\" dateFormat = Format(itm.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd Hmm ") For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments If Right(objAtt.FileName, 5) = ".docx" Then 'THIS LINE IS ADJUSTED fName = saveFolder & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName If Dir(fName) <> "" Then 'file already exists fName = fName & Int(Timer) 'add a number End If objAtt.SaveAsFile fName & ".docx" End If Next End Sub

Comment: @VBA -- ah yes, reminds me of a couple former workplaces of mine!  I'm not sure why `int(timer)` isn't returning a number for you. You could instead try a random number with `int(rnd()*1000)`.  However, if the end goal is to _organize_ these files, there may be an **easier way** (with minimal coding).  I assume these `.docx` files are Word XML files?  Instead of relying on the filename the sender chooses, you could rename them, perhaps _all_ sequentially ie,"File0001.docx", or perhaps there's a field within the document itself that would make a logical file name as well?

Comment: Dear Ashleedawg, I tried the int(rnd()*1000) . This didn't work, and yes the .docx is a Word document. Yes, it is maybe an idea to rename it in File0001 > 2 > 3. - There is no field in the document which is identical.

Comment: @VBA -- see Edit #2 on my answer, above, and let me know if you can get it doing what you need.